# Mongoose. Sort by last object in array

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongoose

I have collection of `Users` like this:

```
[
  { _id: 1, records: [ { honor: 1 },{ honor: 2 } } ]}, 
  { _id: 2, records: [ { honor: 1 },{ honor: 200 } ]}, 
  { _id: 3, records: [ { honor: 1 },{ honor: 20 } ]}, 
]
```

I want to sort `Users` by last element in array `records` in desc order.

Used

```
  User.find()
    .sort({ 'records.honor': 'desc' })
```